# Why isn't C# try catch actually catching the error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, exception, try-catch

Answer is probably something simple but below is my code, I'm just trying to set a ListBox selection based on a value. When the value is valid it works fine.

```
try { Categories.SelectedValue = catString; }
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) { MessageBox.Show("Out of range!"); }
```

When the `catString` value doesn't exist, no textbox alert is shown and I get the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Categories' has a SelectedValue
>   which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
>   Parameter name: value

I've tried catching `Exception` in general, also tried setting the `SelectedValue` to a known value but it doesn't get that far before the error. The actual ListBox does have a defaultvalue set. Why isn't try catch working?

Thanks!

Comment: Winform or other platforms?

Comment: That exception is not thrown by that code in your question. It is thrown somewhere else. Check the call stack of the exception to find out where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you setting the selected value is not the actual point at which the argument is checked for being out of range. That happens within the `ListBox`. You are just setting a property to a text value. The actual exception is not thrown when you set it, but it is thrown when the `ListBox` tries to index by the argument at a later date. I'm not sure how you can catch that exception, but the general way to avoid it is to never allow `SelectedValue` to be a value which is not in the `ListBox` in the first place. Only set `SelectedValue` to a value that is known to be in the `ListBox`.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

> When the selected value is not in the list of available values and a postback is performed, an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is thrown. The following example shows how to catch an invalid value before postback occurs:

```
this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem{ Text="Hello", Value="1" });
if(DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("2") != null) {
    Response.Write("Found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now.. Theoretically this error won't happen naturally but it's getting set via querystring. So, if the user manually typed something incorrect in the URL it could be invalid.

Comment: Right, and to fix that you should check to see if the value the user provides is in the list or not and not set it if it is missing. See my edit above.

Comment: I tried but during the page load when the code is ran, the listbox hasn't been populated yet, perhaps I'll force it to load sooner then do the check.

Comment: I see. Well you will have to do some form of validation regardless as you definitely shouldn't just let it be entered raw. Maybe store it and set it after the load?